# String stored in struct prints incorrectly

Tags: c, string, struct, char

I have several data types defined in my program, and one of them looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
  char     name[MAX_STR];
  int      value;
  DataType dType; 
} VarType;
```

And I would like "initialize" it using function that I've defined as follows:

```
void initVar(VarType *varPtr, char *name, int *val, DataType d)
{
  varPtr = (VarType *) calloc(1,sizeof(VarType));
  strcpy(varPtr->name, name);
  varPtr->dType;

  /* we have to store it differently depending on the type, be careful! */
  if(d==C_INT_PTR)
    varPtr->value = (int)(val);
  else if(d==C_INT)
    varPtr->value = *val;

  /* NOTE THE FOLLOWING LINE */
  printf("The variable name prints properly here: %s\n", varPtr->name);
}
```

Finally, I want to use these structures and methods somewhere else in code, but when I check the name after I've set it using a string literal, it prints jibberish even though within the `initVar()` function it prints perfectly fine.

```
/* let's store the variables we're gonna put in the frame */
VarType vars[3];

initVar(&vars[0], "num", &num, C_INT);
/* NOTE THE FOLLOWING LINE */
printf("This one prints like jibberish: %s\n",vars[0].name);
```

Why doesn't it print the correct string anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `initVar` function, you immediately overwrite the `varPtr` variable so that it points to newly allocated memory instead of `&vars[0]`. Everything within the function uses this newly allocated memory, including the last printf, so it works correctly.

Unfortunately, that means that you didn't actually modify `vars[0]` at all. When you return from the function, you leak the allocated memory, and `vars[0]` stays uninitialized, hence the gibberish.

Your program snippet should work if you delete this line:

```
varPtr = (VarType *) calloc(1,sizeof(VarType));
```

It's not clear, however, if that's what you're trying to do in general.

**A few more thoughts...**

1) Look into using a `union` instead of an `int` for `value`.

2) The statement `varPtr->dType;` doesn't do anything and can be removed.

3) If you're trying to use `calloc` to zero out the structure, try using `memset` instead.

Comment: Fantastic work! I would use union, but this is for school and I was required to use int. The useless varPtr->dType; statement was a mistake, I had it originally assign d to it, but removed that portion of code for debugging. Thank you for pointing that out! And I was able to get away with not dynamically allocating memory at all, I never used either calloc or malloc in my final code.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
VarType vars[3];
```

already initialises an array type of `VarType` with the size of 3.

Here:

```
varPtr = (VarType *) calloc(1,sizeof(VarType));
```

You are overwriting the `vars[0]`

1) Delete `varPtr = (VarType *) calloc(1,sizeof(VarType))`

OR

2) Instead of declaring `VarType` outside of function, change the function type into `VarType` so that it would return a `VarType` pointer

Such as:

```
VarType* initVar(char *name, int *val, DataType d)
{
  VarType* varPtr = (VarType *) calloc(1,sizeof(VarType));
  strcpy(varPtr->name, name);
  varPtr->dType;

  /* we have to store it differently depending on the type, be careful! */
  if(d==C_INT_PTR)
    varPtr->value = (int)(val);
  else if(d==C_INT)
    varPtr->value = *val;

  /* NOTE THE FOLLOWING LINE */
  printf("The variable name prints properly here: %s\n", varPtr->name);
  return varPtr;
}
```

Comment: You've given me multiple options, so +1 for that. I was considering having initVar return a pointer to a VarType, especially because that would make it "feel" a little more like object oriented syntax, but I decided to stray away from it in the end. I also never realized that VarType vars[3] already allocates memory, which should have been quite obvious. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
varPtr = (VarType *) calloc(1,sizeof(VarType));
```

creates a local pointer `varPtr`, which gets destroyed when your function exits. That's why it prints OK in your function, but not in the caller. You need to pass a pointer to it, e.g.:

```
void initVar(VarType ** varPtr, char *name, int *val, DataType d)
{
    VarType * temp_varPtr = calloc(1,sizeof(VarType));

    /*  Rest of function  */

    *varPtr = temp_varPtr;
}
```

Your function has a lot of other errors, though, not the least of which is that you're setting up an array of `VarType` before you call it, and then trying to `calloc()` memory which you already allocated when you set up the array. You should just get rid of that line with `calloc()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line , then it will ok

```
 varPtr = (VarType *) calloc(1,sizeof(VarType))
```

This creates a local variable, which auto destroyed when exiting function